# What is the most secured way to check if a user is already logged in?

Tags: authentication, logging, struts2

I have read many questions like my question title, none of them give me a solution.

I am implement a website (using struts2 framework) and I dont know what is the most secure way to check if user is already logged or not. My site has the payment feature, so I should really be careful about this.

All the solution I have read are similar like this:

```
// Is there a "user" object stored in the user's HttpSession?
    Object user = session.getAttribute (USER_HANDLE);
    if (user == null) {
        // The user has not logged in yet.
    }
    else {
       // the user has logged in
    }
```

I was wondering is there any chance some bad guys can create a fake session object like the user object and then can logged in the system without a valid password?

I also want to know is it practice way, at  every required logged in page, ***not just check the user object is not null, but also check the username and password in the database***?

Comment: why someone would want to close my question? is it not a valid question or duplicate somewhere?

Comment: I have not voted, but I'm not sure this is very constructive: how do user log in? what is the application server? what makes you think Struts 2 can be subject to session hijacking? Also check out [How to prevent session hijacking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422977/how-to-prevent-tomcat-session-hijacking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security issues are always based on your requirements, in simple which kind of security you want ,because there are various layers of security regarding web. But as you have mentioned, This you can achieve using Struts2-Interceptors, because It provides you terminology to perform some essential operation before and after your action is called.For example refer [this link](http://www.2bloggers.com/2010/12/struts-2-with-login-interceptor.html).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use a security framework like [spring security](http://jtechspace.blogspot.com/2012/07/integrating-struts2-with-spring.html) or Apache Shiro.